# Can I store the returned object from Iterator.next() method?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, iterator

I have read that Iterator .next() method returns the object, but I get an error saying it is not a statement. I am pretty new to Java, so help would be very appreciated!

I have tried with both Iterator, Iterator and ListIterator. I get the same error. My code is for homework and is pretty long, so I will just add what I think is most relevant here. Please ask if you need to see more!

```
Iterator<Person> itr = work.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
  Person this = itr.next();
  if (this.birthday == time){
    if (once == 0){
      System.out.println("Birthday: "+time);
      once++;
    }
    work.remove(this);
```

As you can see I am using the stored object multiple times, so I don't think I can use itr.next() several times as it will move to the next value.

My error:

> Homework4.java:145: error: not a statement
>             Person this = itr.next();

Comment: `this` is a reserved name. Try `current`.

Comment: 'this' is a magic word.   Use a different word for your Person variable

Comment: this is reserved, if you change the variable name it will be ok.PS: it will also fail because you try to remove from a list while iterating.

Comment: `this` is a reserved word in java, use smth like `Person person = itr.next();`

Comment: To address the secondary problem mentioned by Sergiu, see [`Iterator#remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()).